# React Native fetch call working in iOS but not Android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I can't seem to get the following fetch call to work on Android. It's not hitting the server and doesn't seem to be throwing any errors. The same code works on iOS. Do I have to do something special to enable network requests for Android on React Native? Thanks in advance.

```
export const login = function(user, success, error) {
        let path='http://localhost:3000/api/session';
        fetch(path, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({user: user})
        }).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        }).then(success).catch(error);
    };
```

Comment: I am also having same problem. How did you manage to work this API?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following permission set in your `AndroidManifest.xml` in `android/app/src/main`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```